# Details View in MVC + Joining Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need some advice / help on this problem. I have been hunting around on the Internet and i'm getting a bit confused.

Basically i have a view - index which lists all my films. There is a details view which shows additional information about the film. The issue i have is when i view the details view it is not showing my some of the values. I understand why as i have a strongly typed model but i need some help on how to fix this.

Model

```
    public class Film
    {
      public int FilmID { get; set; }

      [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 1)]
      [Required]
      public string Title { get; set; }
      ..............

      public Owner owners { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Film film = db.Films.Find(id);

        if (film == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(film);
    }
```

View

```
    @model SwapShop.Models.Film
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    }

    <h2>Details</h2>

    <fieldset>
    <legend>Film</legend>
    <div class="display-label">
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title):
    </div>   
    <div class="display-field">
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.owners.Owner_FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.owners.Owner_FirstName)
    </div>
    </fieldset>
```

The correct record is being displayed but the value for owner_FirstName is blank. Do i need to join the Owner table in the controller?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line: `return View(film)` and check the value of `film`. If `film.owners.Owner_FirstName` is empty, then you'll need to see if the `db.Films.Find()` method is correctly querying your database for the `owners` property.

Comment: Thank for you for getting back so quickly. What is the best way of writing out the values to the screen?

Comment: I managed to inspect the film object and when i view the film title it is being displayed to the console correctly. When i view the films.owners.Owner_FirstName i get a nullrefexception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework, navigation properties like `owners` might not be fetched when you get a film. What about trying this :

```
Film film = db.Films.Include(f=> f.owners).SingleOrDefault(f => f.FilmId == id);
```

Comment: Your a star. Thank you so much for your time on this. I thought it was something to do with that statement but was struggling with what to write. Thanks again.